# Accessing Button in NIB that is in my framework

Tags: cocoa, frameworks

I am trying to create a simple framework with a nib that has a button on it which can be customized (selector wise and title wise.) for this, i did the following:

I added a property:

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSButton*accessoryButton;
```

and connected it to my outlet:

```
@synthesize accessoryButton = littleButton;
```

I then shared the instance as such:

```
+ (TestWindow *)sharedPanel
{
    return sharedPanel ? sharedPanel : [[[self alloc] init] autorelease];
}

- (id)init 
{
    if (sharedPanel) {
        [self dealloc];
    } else {
        sharedPanel = [super init];
    }

    return sharedPanel;
}
```

and load the nib:

```
 if( !somewindow ) 
 {
  [NSBundle loadNibNamed: @"window" owner:nil];
 }
 [NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
 [somewindow center];
 [somewindow setLevel:NSModalPanelWindowLevel];
 [somewindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
```

When I however want to change the title for example from my sample project, it never works.

```
[TestWindow sharedPanel] setTitle:@"hi"]; //doesnt work
```

Here's my setTitle: method:

```
-(void)setTitle:(NSString *)buttonTitle
{
 [[self accessoryButton] setTitle:buttonTitle];
 [[self accessoryButton] display];
}
```

I don't get an error but nothing happens either. What am I missing?

Comment: Don't ever send `[self dealloc]`. Send `[self release]` instead.

Comment: Thanks.Do you have any solutions for my question? :)

Comment: does no one have any solutions at all? :(

Answer (score 0):

Is the button nil at runtime? Are you sure your button's outlet is connected?

Comment: I've tested again, the button does not return nil. `-(void)setTitle:(NSString *)buttonTitle
{
 if (self.accessoryButton == nil)
 {
  NSLog(@"Button is nil");
 }
 [[self accessoryButton] setTitle:buttonTitle];
 [[self accessoryButton] display];
}
`

Answer (score 0):

Does your init function get called when the NIB is loaded?